# jquery equivalent to find value of certain attribute on an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
  <div custom-attribute="somevalue"></div>
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].getAttribute("custom-attribute");
  console.log(x); //somevalue
```

Right now i know its for 0th div but it can be on any random div.

Is there a Jquery equivalent of the above to achieve getting the value of an elements attribute ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.attr()` function.

```js
var x = $("div").attr("custom-attribute");
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div custom-attribute="somevalue"></div>
```

## Resource

- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 2):

JQuery has a `.attr` method which will do what you want:

```js
// Old way:
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].getAttribute("custom-attribute");
console.log(x); //somevalue

// JQuery way:
var y = $("div").attr("custom-attribute");
console.log(y) // somevalue
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div custom-attribute="somevalue"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery selectors take the exact same syntax as CSS selectors, so use the **[attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** to locate the element and then the **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method to extract the attribute value.

```js
var x = $("div[custom-attribute]");
console.log(x.attr("custom-attribute")); //somevalue
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div custom-attribute="somevalue"></div>
```

But, know that custom attributes are invalid HTML unless they take the form of `data-customName`, in which case, you'd still select the element the same way, but you'd access the `data-*` attribute using **[JQuery's `.data()` method](https://api.jquery.com/data/)**, like this:

```js
var x = $("div[data-custom-attribute]");
console.log(x.data("customAttribute")); //somevalue
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-custom-attribute="somevalue"></div>
```

And, just for reference purposes, your original vanilla JavaScript code really should have been very similar in the first place because `.getElementsByTagName()` is going to scan the entire document, which you don't want to do when you are only looking for one element. Additionally, it returns a "live" node list that hinders performance.

```js
var x = document.querySelector("div[data-custom-attribute]");
console.log(x.dataset.customAttribute); //somevalue
```

```html
<div data-custom-attribute="somevalue"></div>
```

Comment: He wants the attribute of the first DIV, not the attribute of the first DIV that has that attribute.

Comment: @Barmar He says it could be any `div`.

Comment: I thought he meant that he might want to change `[0]` to a different index, but it should still be an index of all the DIVs, not just the ones with that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `document.getElementByTagName("name")` is `$("name")`.

The equivalent of indexing the result with `[i]` is `.eq(i)`.

The equivalent of `.getAttribute("attr")` is `.attr("attr").

So the whole thing is:

```
var x = $("div").eq(0).attr("custom-attribute");
```